# How can I simulate the press of a button?

Tags: delphi, button, event-handling, vcl

I want to test some forms. Is there a way to simulate the press of an Ok (or Cancel) button so that the button is pressed and fires the event handlers that are associated with it?

Comment: See also this answer for [delphi-gui-testing-and-modal-forms](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6574035/576719).

Comment: How accurate a simulation do you want? Should the mouse move? Should the button appear pressed on the screen? Should the button receive messages like `wm_LButtonDown`?

Comment: @LU RD, thanks for the pointer! I just wondered how to test modal forms. This helps.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy, I must confess that I hadn't thought thru the problem that far. As for now the answer of David is what I needed. Supopose I needed to go further, what would be your suggestion?

Comment: I can't really recommend anything since I don't know what your needs are.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The cleanest approach is to call the Click method of the button. This is better than the alternatives for these reasons:

- You could read the OnClick property, check that it was not nil, and then call the method. But that seems rather pointless since the Click method already does just that. There's no point duplicating this code.
- And you could call the event handler directly, but that would require your code to have knowledge of it. That implies an undesirable level of coupling to the implementation details.
- Calling `Click` replicates what actually happens when the user clicks. It **is** what happens when the user presses the button. It deals with any actions that are associated with the button, for example. It sets the forms ModalResult property. And so on.

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. I tested it and it works, making it easier for me to test forms. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 7):

`btn_ok.click` or `btn_okClick(sender);`

Answer (score 1):

Calling the `OnClick` event handler won't call the Delphi's default event handler, but just the one implemented by the user. I think you should create your own class derived from `TCustomButton`, and implement a function that calls the `Click` method(it is protected).

Comment: `TCustomButton.Click` is public, not protected.

Comment: Yes, just call `Click` on a `TButton` instance. No need for derivation.

Comment: It is public in VCL, and it is protected in Firemonkey.

Answer (score 0):

A correction for TSpeedButton:

The behavior described by @David Heffernan does not quite hold true for speedbuttons in a group. Calling the Click method does not seem to affect the "Down" status of the buttons.

To solve this I used the following code:

```
MyButton.Click;
MyButton.Down := True;
```

Answer (score -2):

It's better to use the `PerformClick()` method of the Button   =>

```
button1.PerfomClick()
```

If your Button is not in the right state to click (enabled false or not visible), it will not perform the click eventmethod.

Comment: There is not `PerformClick` in the VCL. There is a `PerformClick` in WinForms. Perhaps that's what you are referring to.